# How to manually make firebase dynamic links?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-dynamic-links

first of all, I already read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) but I didn't understand how it works.

I created this link https://postmortem.page.link/?link=https://postmortem.com.mx/obituary/HbdPQ0no41

But it gives me an error and I don't know what should I do. For starters when it says `https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link` what exactly are they referring with `your_subdomain` postmortem.com.mx or postmortem?

All I want to do is use "firebase dynamic links" to create sharable links with a preview with a photo, description, and title. I need to use the dynamic links because the foto and the description are generated using the information in firebase and can't put that on the headers but I can generate a dynamic link with the corresponding photo and description.

**Edit**
This was a huge small mistake, I've been trying multiple url and url combinations and It turns out that I had this rule `/shared/**` and I was writing the dynamic links with `/shared**` without the `/` and that's what confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `your_subdomain` refers to postmortem . It seems you haven't configured a domain for firebase dynamic link. You can do that from the firebase console. Then only you can create valid links.

Comment: But if my subdomain is `postmortem` and I own `postmortem.com.mx` what happens with for example `postmortem.com` which I do not own but has the same sub-domain

Comment: Apart from that, the link does send me to somewhere but it Is not what I put on the link parameter. *Edit* Yes I think I haven't configured the domains correctly

Comment: I found the issue and it was really dumb, but thanks to your answer I manage to see it